# visual studio mvc CRUD templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, templates

Using Visual Studio 2012 / MVC 4

When you create a controller in VS, you get the option to have VS automatically generate CRUD templates for your controller, is it possible to modify these templates or even create your own templates? As every time these templates are created I need to make minor changes to the code it generates, example

this is the code VS generates for my edit template

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
```

but I have to change these evey time to suit my layout, to something like

```
<section>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)

            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>
    </Section>
```

Comment: See this article http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx

Comment: @Omar, thanks thats perfect (I cant reward you the answer as you have only added a comment!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comment from Omar for the answer